# How can we write a shell script using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I need to read CSV file, process the file via REST API call and then write the output in another CSV file. The requirement is strictly shell script using NodeJs.

I am using Windows platform

Comment: I do not need to run shell script via nodejs. I need to make node code run like shell script. Like if I click the script file or run some node command, it executes all the things written in the node script.

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: I need to run it on window platform

Answer (score 1):

You could add a shebang to your .js file and make it executable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log('...')
```

Alternatively you make a wrapper bash script and execute whatever you want

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
node whatever.js
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on linux, start your script with the following line:

`#!/usr/bin/env node`

This would indicate that node interpreter should be used to execute this file.

Then make the file executable:

`chmod +x your_script.js`

At this point it should be possible to run script as any regular executable, e.g:

`./your_script.js`